# How to distinguishing variable uppercase characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have query:

```
DECLARE @P_Param nvarchar(100) = 'HELLO WORLD'
select @p_param
```

When `@P_Param <>  @p_param` but it had return result?

I don't want it.

I want it have notice error!

I using sql server 2014.

Plase help me!

Comment: You mean you want case sensitive variable names?

Comment: why you want it have notice error?

Comment: *The SQL Keywords are case-insensitive ( SELECT , FROM , WHERE , etc), but are often written in all caps. However in some setups table and column names are case-sensitive.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559254/case-sensitive-variables-in-sql-server