# Must declare the scalar variable "@id" error with stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-cursor

I got this procedure with a cursor

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Inventario
AS
    DECLARE @Id int, @Nombre varchar(255), @precio decimal, @st int, @inv int
    SET @inv = 0

    DECLARE cproducto CURSOR FOR
        SELECT P.ProductID, P.ProductName, P.UnitPrice, P.UnitsInStock
        FROM Products P
```

and

```
OPEN cproducto

FETCH cproducto INTO @id, @Nombre, @precio, @st

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    PRINT Str(@id) + space(5) + str(@nombre) + space(5) +  Str(@precio) + space(5) + Str(@st)

    SET @inv += @st

    FETCH cproducto INTO @id, @Nombre, @precio, @st
END

CLOSE cproducto
DEALLOCATE cproducto 

PRINT 'Inventario de Productos:' + Str(@inv)
```

I get this error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@id"

multiple times, could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: please specify what RDBMS are you using.

Comment: SQL SERVER 2017 using NORTHWND database

Comment: Is your database collation case sensitive? You declared `@Id` with uppercase but use `@id`.

Comment: It's not case sensitive

Comment: The query you've pasted would not produce that error (so long as the top part and the bottom part are in the same scope)...

Comment: @Batam what collation are you using? `SELECT collation_name FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id = DB_ID();`

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6559516/4020264, maybe your server's collation is case sensitive.

Comment: check may be its case sensitive, you declared as `@Id` and using as `@id`

Comment: It's not case sensitive i can tell. Also just to prove it i tried it right now, same error.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you need `begin`/`end`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Inventario
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Id int, @Nombre varchar(255), @precio decimal, @st int, @inv int;
    SET @inv=0;
    DECLARE cproducto CURSOR FOR
    SELECT  P.ProductID, P.ProductName, P.UnitPrice, P.UnitsInStock
    FROM Products P;

    . . .
END;
```

Comment: It still says: Must declare the scalar variable "@id" :(

Comment: @Bata . . . `@id` is declared in the stored procedure.  Is all your code between the `begin` and `end`?

Comment: Yes that's all of it