# SQL command returning null for value

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am previously only familiar with Linq and the like for data access. I am working on something now that requires me to use actual SQL commands on the back end to return a single value. My code compiles and runs, however it is returning null for a value that I know should be returning something besides an empty string...

Is my structure off on this? Or is something else missing?

Below is my code:

```
  internal string GetSexDescription(string sex, int id_merchant)
    {
        string newSex = "";

        var builder = new ConnectionStringHelper();
        var connString = builder.getCasinoDBString(id_merchant);

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            string sql = "SELECT Description FROM person_gender_lookup WHERE ID = @sex";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            try
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sex", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sex;

                newSex = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            return newSex;
        }
    }
```

Here is a picture of the result set of the table:

[image]

Comment: This looks good, have u tried running the query in the DBMS?

Comment: Just a guess: the parameter name could be case sensitive.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes not in Sql Server at least.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes but "sex" is the actual parameter name being passed into this function

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes ahh nvm i see now

Comment: I am not speaking of the C# method parameter but of the SQL parameter `@sex` which is completely unrelated to C# variable names. You add the command parameter as `@Sex` but specify `@sex` in the sql command text. According to the SO question [Case sensitive variables in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559254/case-sensitive-variables-in-sql-server), this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6559516/880990) says: *"The identifiers for variables, GOTO labels, temporary stored procedures, and temporary tables are in the default collation of the server instance."*.

Comment: Can you show the table definition for the person_gender_lookup table?  You are comparing the ID from that table to a text string, but generally ID fields are unique Integer columns (probably auto incrementing), so, I'd like to confirm the data type of the ID field.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Yes, i saw that. Thought it was capitalized as well.. I changed it to accommodate and still returning a null value.

Comment: @MichaelDougan yes, unfortunately the ID is being passed from a data within a model that I did not create.. It was poorly structured this way. I can't change it without affecting too many other things. ID should be a "1".

Comment: So, 1 is male, 0 is female?

Comment: @spodger 0 would be male, 1 female

Comment: How is the column declared? As `ID int` or as `ID varchar(10)` or something?

Comment: Did you check the console for an exception message? You're not opening the connection, which will lead to an exception being thrown.

Comment: Can you verify that you are getting a valid connect string, and that the table in that database has data that matches your test criteria?

Comment: @MichaelDougan table does have data. Let me check the conn string

Comment: @MichaelDougan, connection string is indeed valid

Comment: OP updated to show results set of table.

Answer (score 2):

Open the connection.

```csharp
internal string GetSexDescription(string sex, int id_merchant)
{
   string newSex = "";

   var builder = new ConnectionStringHelper();
   var connString = builder.getCasinoDBString(id_merchant);

   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
   {
      conn.Open(); //<- This line here.
      string sql = "SELECT Description FROM person_gender_lookup WHERE ID = @sex";

      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
      try
      {
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sex", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sex;

         newSex = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      }

      return newSex;
   }
}
```

`cmd.ExecuteScalar()` is probably throwing an `InvalidOperationException` because you haven't opened the connection. The exception is being caught, outputted to the console, then the initial value of `newSex` is begin returned since the call to `ExecuteScalar` threw.

Comment: You are correct. Also had to close it after I assigned the variable to the output.

Answer (score 1):

ID is a int or varchar?
If is int use:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@sex", SqlDbType.Int).Value = sex;
```

instead of:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sex", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sex;
```

P.S.
Query parameters and parameter add into cmd.Parameters is case sensitive.

Write

```
@sex
```

instead of

```
@Sex
```

Comment: ID in the table is an int... however how the rest of the project is set up, it was wrongfully passing a string for ID instead of an int. If I were to re-structure, I would have to undo a lot of things already in motion unfortunately..

Comment: You also miss conn.Open();

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Had to open the cmd and close it AFTER I set the newSex variable to the value being pulled.

```
   internal string GetSexDescription(string sex, int id_merchant)
    {
        string newSex = "";

        var builder = new ConnectionStringHelper();
        var connString = builder.getCasinoDBString(id_merchant);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                string sql = "SELECT Description FROM person_gender_lookup WHERE ID = @Sex";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sex", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sex;
                    adapter.Fill(ds);

                    newSex = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                    conn.Close();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }

                return newSex;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What are SqlDataAdapter and DataSet doing here? They are not necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
internal string GetSexDescription(string sex, int id_merchant)
{
    string newSex = "";

    var builder = new ConnectionStringHelper();
    var connString = builder.getCasinoDBString(id_merchant);

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        string sql = "SELECT Description FROM person_gender_lookup WHERE ID" +  sex;;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        try
        {


            newSex = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return newSex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. See: [SQL Injection (w3schools)](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp), [SQL injection (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Don't even think the SQL string is valid anyway.